# Cómo encontrar una cadena en javascript delimitada por corchetes como [TEXTO]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo entendido que se puede separar con `.split (" ")`, pero me gustaría encontrar textos dentro de un cierto carácter específico, tal como `[`...`]`

Ejemplo:

```html
<div>[text1][text2]</div>
<!-- Otra forma -->

<div id="Seach-Text">Lorem Ipsum is [simply] dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard</div>
```

Para el primer caso, busco simplemente dos cadenas de palabras, tal como se ve en el codigo `<div>[text1][text2]</div>`, que divida en dos variables T1, T2 e imprima dichas variables `text1` y `text2`.

```js
var T1 = "text1";
var T2 = " text2";

// <!-- Otra forma -->

var T3 = "simply";
```

Comment: Intentaste con expresiones regulares y replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Código

```js
var regex = /\[([^\]]+)]/g,
    match,
    resultado = [],
    texto = "[text1][text2]Lorem Ipsum is [simply] dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard";

//bucle para todas las coincidencias
while ((match = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
    resultado.push(match[1]);
}

//se obtienen todos los resultados en un array
console.log("Se encontró:", resultado);

//..o se puede obtener resultado[0], resultado[1], etc.
var T1 = resultado[0];
var T2 = resultado[1];

//mostrar el resultado
document.getElementById("resultado")
        .innerText = "Primera palabra: " + T1
                   + "\nSegunda palabra: " + T2;
```

```html
<p>Resultado:</p>
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

[<kbd>Demo en regex101.com</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/gOf6TV/1)

#### Descripción

Utilizamos la expresión regular

```regex
/\[([^\]]+)]/g
```

Que coincide con:

- `\[` - El caracter literal `"["`
- `([^\]]+)` - Es un grupo que grabará el texto que coincide con:

  - `[^\]]+` - Cualquier caracter, excepto `"]"` , cuantas veces pueda coincidir.
- `]` - El caracter literal `"]"`
- Modificador `/g` - para encontrar todas las coincidencias (no sólo la primera).

Y esto lo aplicamos en un bucle, mientras `regex.exec(texto)`[▶️](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) tenga resultados.

Al haber utilizado un grupo, el texto que coincidió con ese primer grupo se obtiene dentro del bucle como `match[1]`.

Comment: Gracias @mariano es lo que estuve buscando exactamente, que las palabras encontradas entre `( )` paracentesis den resultados en  variables distintos.

Answer (score 5):

Depende de lo que quieres conseguir, si es sólo búsqueda, te recomendaría usar el método *match de String.*

Funciona de la siguiente manera: introduces una expresión regular y lo que se halle entre paréntesis `( )` será capturado. Te devolverá un conjunto (array) con **los elementos capturados**.

```js
//Tu Texto
let text = `some [sample] text [here] hehe. <div> htm[l]? </div>`;
//String match
text.match(/\[([\w\s]*)\]/g)
  .forEach((item) => {
    //console.log( item );
    //Puedes limpiar el texto con:
    console.log( item.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '') );
  });
```

La parte importante aquí es que en la expresión regular ponemos una `g` al final para que busque en toda la cadena.

#### Explicación

La expresión regular `/\[([\w\s]*)\]/g` busca cualquier cosa que sea carácter `\w` o espacio `\s` cero o más veces `[\w\s]*` (Nota: `[]` quiere decir que se encontrará una de las cosas dentro del paréntesis) y luego envolvemos esto en `\[ \]` que básicamente quieren decir que busque literalmente `[` o `]` porque usamos la barra inversa `\` para indicar que no quiere decir lo que he mencionado anteriormente sobre escojer uno u otro, si no que busque literalmente eso. Finalmente, marcamos con una `g` el final de la expresión para que busque lo que queremos.

En definitiva, lo que a ti te va a servir es un conjunto de palabras, que es lo que buscas:

```
let conjunto = text.match(/\[([\w\s]*)\]/g);
```

Si te interesa como limpiar el array de los carácteres `[` y `]` con un `map` valdría, pero se sale de la pregunta.

Más información sobre `String.prototype.match()` [MDN: String Match](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match)

Más información sobre `RegExp` [MDN: Expresión Regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)

Comment: Sep, tienes razón! Creo que la tuya es más especifica, gracias por la aportación! ^^

Comment: Muchas gracias @SigmaSoldier , la explicación es muy bueno, Gracias por ayudarme.

Answer (score 4):

Tu planteamiento presenta el siguiente problema:

- Si los resultados se limitan a Dos (2) por cadena, podrías almacenarlos en las variables.
- Si los resultados son múltiples, en cambio, el planteamiento no funciona porque en vez de variables te recomendaría el uso de un objeto ó un arreglo.

En todo caso, creo que esto es lo que buscas:

```js
str = "Lorem Ipsum is [simply] dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard";

var T1 = str.match(/\[(.*)\]/).pop();

alert(T1);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @JuanFernandoz,

Comment: Es lo que buscaba, quise plantear dos formas, la primera es <div>[text1][text2]</div>

Comment: y es simplemente dos cadenas de palabras en este caso, tal como se ve en el codigo <div>[text1][text2]</div>, que divida en dos variables T1, T2 e imprima dichas variables text1 y text2.

Comment: Esto fallaría para `antes[text1]algo en el medio[text2]después`, ya que coincidiría con `[text1]algo en el medio[text2]`.